# CPU Frequency scaling can't be disable in menuconfig

Tags: kernel, compiling

I am trying to build a Linux-5.15.94 kernel with preempt_rt patch. But when navigating to menu `Power management and ACPI options --> CPU Frequency scaling`, I just find the option `CPU Frequency scaling` can't be disabled. What causes this, and how could I disable it? ? [image: Screenshot of Menuconfig],

I really wonder, why is the sysbom ahead of `CPU Freqency scaling` is `-*-`, what does this imply (as compared to `<*>`, `[*]`)?

Comment: I'm not sure what this has to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I am trying to build a new kernel for my Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

-*- means it cannot be toggled at the moment; if you press "?" to see the help text, you can see which other configured options force it to be on (this could be different for everybody).

As for the modifiable <*> vs. [*]: I believe <*> means the feature could be compiled as a loadable module or compiled into the kernel (trading flexible memory usage and the ability to turn off features by unloading modules vs. longer initial read time of a larger kernel with all features baked in. E.g., the governors in the provided screenshot can be disabled, loaded on demand via separate modules, or baked into the kernel for faster switching between them at the expense of (little) memory and a (slightly) longer initial read of the larger kernel file on boot. [*] can only be toggled on or off, so these are flags for a feature rather than a separate feature that can potentially be loaded. E.g., I would assume the CPU frequency transition statistics are tracked by the CPU frequency scaling feature, but people who do not want or need them can toggle them off (for perhaps slightly more speed and less clutter).